# Is there a way to stub all methods of a particular class in RSpec 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a self-made service class that is helping me DRY up the sending of push notifications and I'd like to be able to stub all methods belonging to the class.

I'm thinking of something like

```
# Service Class
class PushService
  def self.send_message
    ...
  end

  def self.send_payment_confirmation
    ...
  end
end
```

In my spec tests, I'd like to be able to do

```
RSpec.describe "blah" do
  before do
    allow(PushService).to receive_everything.and_return({})
  end

end
```

I've looked around and it appears that stub_everything() has been deprecated and it is recommended to use double's `as_null_object` but I'm not sure how that works.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `stub_everything` is deprecated.

Yes, you can use `as_null_object` to stub everything in your test like this:

```
let(:push_service) { double(PushService).as_null_object }
```

When you use `as_null_object`, your object will respond to any method that is not implemented. It will also allow you to use explicit stubs and explicit expectations.

See [Null object doubles](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/null-object-doubles) documentation for more information.

Comment: how does this work? Your code may be using the `PushService` class directly.